# why ngModel write value two times

Tags: angular

I wrote a custom form control that implemented the `ControlValueAccessor` Interface.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  template: `
    <button (click)="increase($event)">+</button>
    {{counter}}
    <button (click)="decrease($event)">-</button>
  `,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CounterComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  private counter: number = 0;
  private onChange: (_: any) => void;
  private onTouched: () => void;

  ngOnInit() { }

  writeValue(value) {
    console.log('Write value', value);
    this.counter = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

  increase() {
    this.counter++;
    this.onChange(this.counter);
  }
  decrease() {
    this.counter--;
    this.onChange(this.counter);
  }
}
```

But I found that writeValue would trigger two times when I use `ngModel`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<counter [(ngModel)]="count"></counter>',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  count = 5;
}
```

[output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGgYc.png)

```
Write value null
Write value 5
```

The online example link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-write-value

Comment: can you explain how the writeValue is triggered ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I'm not sure about this. I guess it would be triggered when ngmodel changed. Could you please give some explain or a post link about that ?

Comment: i am not sure of this method jsut wanted to check how it triggers so as to give any answers

Comment: @RahulSingh Thanks any way. I read the source code of `ngModel`, but I could'nt where find the method trigger. I don't konw what I miss.

Answer (score 2):

This is an open defect in the angular project - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14988